# App Loading and Splash Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

My app downloads quite a lot of data, which takes about a few seconds. My splash screen displays and then disappears and then a white blank screen appears for a few seconds before the first view is loaded. Is there a way to keep the splash screen appearing? Is it okay to create a view in the AppDelegate and keep it displayed until all the data loading has been completed and the view is about to load?

Comment: In my opinion you should load that data in the background if possible and let the UI be responsive.

Comment: @Nayefc: +1 for good question :)

Comment: @dasdom Yeah I can do that - using multithreading and GCD but the UI has nothing to display without the data. Plus, this only happens upon the initial launch of the app so I will probably show a nice activity indicator with some background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use MBProgressHUD You can get the whole source code here.

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Hope this helps.

This is a Loading View which is Activity Indicator.

EDIT:

You can add your background view into window while your data is being downloaded in background using

```
[window addSubview:<backgroundView>.view];
```

Then once data is downloaded, you can remove the same from window and add your main view controller into window

```
[<backgroundView>.view removeFromSuperView];
[window addSubview:<mainView>.view];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah I was already using MBProgressHUD. Should I just display a background image behind the activity indicator? SO I would create a view with an image in the AppDelegate, stick the ProgressHUD on top and remove it when the view is about to load. Is that a good solution?

Comment: No thats not required but minimize the time for which the user has to wait by performing data fetching process asynchronously. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I am downloading data asynchronously. But the progressHUD looks quite ugly on a white background for a few seconds which is why I want to stick some nice background for a few seconds. Something simple.

Comment: Also It is possible to display background, you can display some nice backgorund if you want.

Comment: Yeah that would be fine. You can add a view in appdelegate right into the window as a subview to window and once data is downloaded you can remove the view with background from the window using `removeFromSuperview` and then you can add your viewController with your data into window as its subview. This way it would look nice and innovative. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks :) I will mark you as the correct answer as soon as I can in around 3 minutes.

Comment: Check the **EDIT** section of my answer.

Comment: @Nayefc: Hey Nayefc Thank you that you liked my answer. if you have got your answer, please do mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

YEs, you can display a view with a splash screen (and maybe an activity indicator, just remember to load your data in a separate thread, or it won't spin), then switch to the proper View when the loading is done.

Answer (score 1):

The white view that you see before the actual view is the mainWindow. Sinply set the splash image as background image of your window in the MainWindow.xib, and you're done. Optionally you can also add a spinner that is always spinning on top of the window, so that when your app is loading you first see the splash screen, then the spalsh screen with the spinner and then your view appears.

Answer (score 0):

I do load an ImageView with an default-Image in viewDidLoad and hide it if you the data is preceeded.

```
    UIImage* imageDefault = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default@2x.png"];
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = -20;
    frame.size.width = 320;
    frame.size.height = 480;

    splash = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    [splash setImage:imageDefault];
    [self.view addSubview:splash];
   .
   .


    splash.hidden=YES;
```